# MessageBox in file drag+drop event-handler causes Windows explorer to freeze

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

**Scenario:** C#/WPF application with dragdrop enabled for a UI-Control. When dragging a file from Windows Explorer and dropping it on the UI-Control a MessageBox appears.

**Problem:** As long as the MessageBox is not clicked away (by hitting "OK") Windows Explorer is frozen and (probably) waits for the drag-drop event to return.

**Question:** Is there any way to release Windows Explorer from its wait *before* the MessageBox is shown? What about the "[Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)" property of the "DragEventArgs" Class?

**Code:**

```
 private void OnDrop_ButtonOpen(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
   {
     string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
     MessageBox.Show(files[0]);
   }
 }
```

PS: Others similar questions exist. However, no solution to "prematurely" return the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at [**this documentation article about Drag and Drop operations**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905(v=vs.85).aspx) we can see that it says:

> When the user starts a drag-and-drop operation, the source creates a data object and initiates a *drag loop* by calling DoDragDrop.

So the source window is now stuck in a loop started by the [**`DoDragDrop` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486(v=vs.85).aspx).

As the cursor enters another window (known as the *target window*) the `DoDragDrop` function will call the `DragEnter` and `DragOver` methods of the target window's `IDropTarget` interface.

When you release the mouse button to drop the data onto the target window, the `DoDragDrop` function will call the `Drop` method of the `IDropTarget` interface. If we then continue reading...

> When the target is finished with the data object, ***it returns from IDropTarget::Drop***. The system ***returns the source's DoDragDrop call*** to notify the source that the data transfer is complete.

...we see that the source window's `DoDragDrop` call isn't exited until the target window has exited its `IDropTarget::Drop` method.

In .NET when the `IDropTarget::Drop` method is called it will raise the `DragDrop` event. Raising the event means that it calls all attached `DragDrop` event handlers, and since this isn't asynchronous the calling method (`IDropTarget::Drop`) will be blocked until all `DragDrop` event handlers have been called and exited.

**So to answer your question:** No, you cannot return it "prematurely". It is blocked by the standard logic of per-thread code execution: one line at a time.

Your best options here are:

1. Start a task/a new thread where you show the message box. You might have to create a message loop for that, but I'm not 100% sure.
2. Create your own message box form and show it using the non-modal call `Form.Show()`.

Comment: Eventually the MessageBox will be replaced by a (potentially time consuming) loading of the filedrop into memory. However, the app should be able to open a file by a common open file dialog too. My sw-architectural-beginner-gut-feeling tells me (possibly incorrectly) that no matter how the filename/path comes across (dragdrop or dialog) the same file-load-function should be used. However, perhaps there is no contradiction here. Maybe the same load-file-function can be called both from the open-dialog context _and_ from an "abroad" task?

Comment: @AddeTbkg : Yes, a general function is the best. And yes, the function can be called from both the OFD and another thread/task. Keep in mind though that threads and tasks have to invoke to access the UI.